# How to open a note, add an image attachment in evernote (WP7) from another app(that im developing)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I must create a note with image as skitch does from another app like skitch( that im developing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App-to-app communication is not available is Mango, but is rumoured to be part of Apollo (WP8).

Your only choice right now is to communicate with the Evernote's server APIs (assuming there are any).